# exported Eclipse code formatting preferences; imported on another computer but formatting is still different

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

For good or bad we prefer to keep our annotations on the same line as the thing being annotated, as in:

```
@JsonProperty private int foo;
```

In my eclipse I go to Java -> Code Style -> Formatter, select our profile and edit. From there I go to the New Lines tab and uncheck all the before/after options for annotations.  Life is Good.

Then I export my preferences, reload them on another computer...verify that that the settings are the same but when I run format on the new computer I get

```
@JsonProperty
private int foo;
```

Is there some other property that a) controls this and b) isn't included when I export preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a separate export for the Formatter Profile - the button is at the top right of the Profile page. Import and Export All are for the Java / Code Style / Formatter page.